# Does a Jewish-owned supermarket need to completely seal its chametz product aisles?

Tags: halacha, passover, business, selling-mechirat-chametz

Follow up to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/57040/sold-chametz-being-visible):

In almost all the Jewish-owned supermarkets that I have seen, the store owner completely seals the chametz aisles by placing a huge cardboard "wall" at both ends of the aisle and taping it so that no customers can enter it.

I somewhat understand that they don't want their customers to accidentally buy chametz by entering the aisle. However, I can see one problem with this.

If the non-Jewish chametz owner, Favolio, comes into the supermarket on Hol hamo'ed and says that he wants to take a case of linguini (he's making pasta for Pesach ;-), the owner would have to take down the wall for him, no? A bit bothersome, perhaps.

Also, if I understand correctly, the chametz may be visible, anyway, no? Doesn't it suffice to place a sign at the ends of the aisle saying, "Do not enter except for Favolio?"

Comment: I thought Alfredo would be making Fettuccine :)

Comment: @DoubleAA - I said linguini, not fettuccini. Alas, there's a machlokes on how to spell it - fettuccini or fettuccine. I think that the word with the "e" is plural ;-)

Comment: So what about this is a real question? Yes, they ***could*** do it that way (although Bal Yira'eh gets a bit... dicey) but they don't... The concern re: sealing aisles seems more geared toward the non-religious jews or the aides of religious ones who might accidentally grab chametz (possibly from the exposed end shelves) if the aisle is left open

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky OK, place as an answer if you can explain "although Bal Yira'eh gets a bit... dicey". Which part and / or why?

Comment: @DanF Potentially, they would need to sell the aisles in which the chametz is placed (mekomo muschar) to avoid violating lo yimatzei bivateichem. I haven't had a chance to look inside today, though.